# question concerning MetaPost usage

Tags: metapost

Dear Frank Mittelbach,

I bought your book "The LaTeX Graphics Companion", second edition.

I have a question concerning a MetaPost example in that book, p. 174 above.
I have put this in a file called "example.mp". Below my exploits on MetaPost usage:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/.../plot$ ls

example.log example.mp LaTeX Graphics Companion, 2nd ed., excerpts.pdf p. 174.pdf

ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/.../plot$ cat example.mp

input piechartmp
SetupColors((.7,.7),this,this);
SetupPercent(this, " %");
Segment(50,"Lions"); Segment(30,"Tigers");
Segment(10,"Hyaena"); Segment(20,"Monkeys");
Segment(20,"Warthogs");
SegmentState(4,this,0.3);
SegmentState(5,invisible,this);
PieChart(2cm,0.15,60,0,0);
Label.auto(0)(name)(outwards,0);
Label(3,4,5)(value)(inwards,0) withcolor white;
Label(1,2)(percent)(inwards,0) withcolor (1,1,0);
Label.lrt(3)("a segment with ",percent)
((0.9,0.8),(0,-2cm)) withcolor .8red;
pickup pencircle scaled 2pt;
Label.auto(2)("a green label")
((0.9,0.1),(-1cm,7mm)) withcolor .8green;

ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/.../plot$ mpost example.mp

This is MetaPost, version 1.504 (kpathsea version 6.0.1)
(mpost.mp (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004)) (./example.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/metapost/piechartmp/piechartmp.mp))
*^C

ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/.gvfs/.../plot$
```

In the `example.log` file there is nothing written.

Nevertheless MetaPost loads both `example.mp` & `piechartmp.mp`.

What must I do to proceed and obtain an `.eps` file?

Please let me hear something.

Regards,

Francky Leyn

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional information or ask a new follow-up, if appropriate. Please do not use answers to ask further questions.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

You should include your drawing code into the `beginfig()`… `endfig` flags and end your file with the `end` instruction, otherwise nothing will be produced.

```
input piechartmp;
beginfig(1);
SetupColors((.7,.7),this,this);
SetupPercent(this, " %");
Segment(50,"Lions"); Segment(30,"Tigers");
Segment(10,"Hyaena"); Segment(20,"Monkeys");
Segment(20,"Warthogs");
SegmentState(4,this,0.3);
SegmentState(5,invisible,this);
PieChart(2cm,0.15,60,0,0);
Label.auto(0)(name)(outwards,0);
Label(3,4,5)(value)(inwards,0) withcolor white;
Label(1,2)(percent)(inwards,0) withcolor (1,1,0);
Label.lrt(3)("a segment with ",percent)
((0.9,0.8),(0,-2cm)) withcolor .8red;
pickup pencircle scaled 2pt;
Label.auto(2)("a green label")
((0.9,0.1),(-1cm,7mm)) withcolor .8green;
endfig;
end.
```

[image]

More precisely, the output of your statements between `beginfig(n)` and `endfig` flags, where `n` is an integer, will be saved in an `yourfilename.n` file, which is in fact an `mps` file (MetaPost PostScript, a subset of EPS). If you omit the final `end` instruction, MetaPost will enter interactive mode and be waiting for another instruction of yours. Note that a single `.mp` file can produced several drawings, each one corresponding to a different pair of `beginfig()… endfig` flags (with different integer arguments, of course).

Comment: Maybe `input piechart` doesn't require a semicolon, but adding it seems clearer.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't require it, but you're right, it would be less confusing so. Done.

Comment: I've rolled back this answer to remove the addition of the OP's edit because this information should be edited into the question, not being part of the answer.

Comment: When I open this with `gv`, I get an error, namely: https://gist.github.com/d50cb32135077a63817d

Comment: @FaheemMitha Probably the same problem (and solution) as here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279967/ps2pdf-crahes-on-metapost-generated-eps-figure

Comment: Great, you are back.