# ps2pdf crahes on MetaPost generated .eps figure

Tags: metapost, ps2pdf

I generated with MetaPost the example in "LaTeX Graphics Companion", 2nd ed.,
p. 174, above. The eps is generated. The header:

```
%!PS %%BoundingBox: -123 -92 64 43 
%%HiResBoundingBox: -122.84787 -91.07129 63.67152 42.51074 
%%Creator: MetaPost 1.504 
%%CreationDate: 2015.11.25:1112 
%%Pages: 1 
%*Font: cmr10 9.96265 9.96265 20:8400f080008c080065df394 
%%BeginProlog 
%%EndProlog 
%%Page: 1 1
```

However, when I want to view it with Inkscape, I get some error:

ps2pdf failed:

```
Error: /undefined in cmr10 
Operand stack: (Lions) 
Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1910 1 3 %oparray_pop 1909 1 3 %oparray_pop 1893 1 3 %oparray_pop 1787 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- %errorexec_pop .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- 
Dictionary stack: --dict:1165/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)-- --dict:77/200(L)-- 
Current allocation mode is local 
Current file position is 2508 
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Why is this? Are additional steps required, next to "mpost example.mp"?

Regards,

Francky

Comment: The font `cmr10` is probably only referred to in the EPS, and thus things may break. You might want to look up `prologues` in the metapost manual

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

You should insert the following lines at the beginning of your MetaPost file:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.eps";
```

The second line will change the name `example.1` into `example-1.eps` and make the EPS file more easily handled as such by external programs. The first one allows complete font inclusion in your resulting EPS file, which is better in most cases.

If you only mean to include your file in a LaTeX document, it is enough to insert the single line

```
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.mps";
```

instead.

Another solution is to use the `mptopdf` utility which should be part of your TeX installation. The command line

```
 mptopdf example.1
```

will convert your EPS file into a PDF file, `example-1.pdf`.

See the [MetaPost documentation](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf) for more information.